# ¿Cómo Utilizar password_verify()?

Tags: php, seguridad, hash, contraseña, sha1

Soy un verdadero novato en PHP y espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Estoy haciendo un sistema de inicio de sesión básico, ya logre integrar password_hash y que este se almacene en la base de datos, sin embargo no se como integrar password_verify.

Espero alguien pueda hecharme un poco de luz

Como nota adicional, ya leí la documentación de PHP al respecto y sigo sin enternder como integrarlo

El código que controla el inicio de sesión es el siguiente

```
if(isset($_POST["login"])){

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $query =mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");

    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)

    {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $dbusername=$row['username'];
    $dbpassword=$row['password'];
    }

    if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword)

    {


    $_SESSION['session_username']=$username;
```

Tiene esa estructura porque antes solo comparaba contraseñas en texto plano, pero ahora quiero que compare el hash con el almacenado en la base de datos.

Agradezco a todos su ayuda.

Así es como se registran en la página

```
if(!empty($_POST['full_name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $full_name=$_POST['full_name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];


    $password_hash=password_hash("$password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
    $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");
    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows==0)
    {
    $sql="INSERT INTO usertbl
            (full_name, email, username,password)
            VALUES('$full_name','$email', '$username', '$password_hash')";

    $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré hacer que funcionara, ya verifica la contraseña con password_verify()

El código completo es el siguiente

```
if(isset($_POST["login"])){

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    // Reseteamos
    $dbusername = $dbpassword = $password = NULL;

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");

    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows!=0) {
     if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
         $dbusername=$row['username'];
         $dbpassword=$row['password'];
  }
}

// Contraseña obtenido desde login (no hay que encriptarla, tiene que ser origianl)
$password = $_POST['password']; // Contraseña obtenido desde formulario

// Verificar contraseña
if (password_verify($password, $dbpassword)) {


    $_SESSION['session_username']=$username;

    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: intropage.php");
    }
     else {

 $message =  "Nombre de usuario ó contraseña invalida!";
    }

} else {
    $message = "Todos los campos son requeridos!";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para usar password_verify()

Según la documentación, solo tienes que dar un hash y compararlo con una cadena, es decir:

```
<?php
  // este sería el hash que tu darías o en tu caso $password_hash
  $hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
} else {
    echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
}
?>
```

Lo único que tendrías que hacer es comparar en la funcion `password_verify` la cadena de la contraseña que tuviere por tu variable $password_hash