# Implementación de password_verify() y password_hash() para la validación de usuarios en el login

Tags: php

Traigo esta duda en base a una conversación con @gbianchi en donde él me decía que en un login el user y password se deben verificar al mismo tiempo y yo en teoría lo hago, pero ahora que le pongo más cabeza, me surge una duda con `password_verify()`.

Según la documentación uno debe comparar el hash de la DB con el del pass tal cual el usuario lo manda desde el form ([Un post de referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460888/c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-password-verify)). Para eso yo uso:

```php
$user = todasLasVerificaciones($_POST['user']);
$pass = todasLasVerificaciones($_POST['pass']);

$dbUser = $querys->getUser($user);
if ($dbUser) {
        $userPassword = $dbUser[0]["password"];
        if (password_verify($pass, $userPassword)){
            $userID = $dbUser[0]["id"];
            $userDB = $dbUser[0]["user"];
// Resto de Codigo
```

*getUser()*

```php
public function getUser($user){
    $sql = "SELECT id, user, email, password, status, verified, auth2fa_secret FROM users WHERE user = '$user' OR email = '$user' ";
    $result = $this->dbm->queryFunction($sql);
    $usuario = $this->dbm->whileFunction($result);
    if ($this->dbm->numRowsFunction($result) > 0) {
        return $usuario;
    }
}
// El OR es por si hacen login con Usuario (pepito) o Email (pepito@gmail.com)
```

Y se supone que está bien, porque yo hago el `password_verify` tal cual lo dice la documentación.

Pero entonces ¿qué pasa si yo hago esto?:

```php
$user = todasLasVerificaciones($_POST['user']);
$pass = todasLasVerificaciones($_POST['pass']);

$dbUser = $querys->getUser($user);

// Imprimo el result de la query
print_r($dbUser);

if ($dbUser) {
        $userPassword = $dbUser[0]["password"];
        if (password_verify($pass, $userPassword)){
            $userID = $dbUser[0]["id"];
            $userDB = $dbUser[0]["user"];
// Resto de Codigo
```

Tengo todo el array de la DB de mi usuario incluso antes de verificar el Password. ¿Eso es correcto a nivel técnico?

Y si no es correcto, y lo correcto es como dice gbianchi (verificar user y pass en la misma query), ¿lo correcto sería pasar el password del form por `password_hash` y compararlo con el de la DB?

Pero si es así, `password_verify` ya no tiene sentido, porque ya he logrado verificar que mi hash de la DB es igual al hash que creo con el pass que el usuario pone en el formulario.

Y ahí es donde tengo el loop :-S

Comment: Hola. No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Qué es **`$sanedPass`** y de dónde sacas esa variable? La cuestión con `password_verify` es comprobar que la contraseña que introduce el usuario coincide con el hash que se guardó, al momento de ingresar dicha contraseña la primera vez, asumiendo que en ese primer momento usaste `password_hash`. En lo adelante, cada vez que el usuario ingresa, tomas la contraseña que él postea y la compruebas con el hash que hay en la BD.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya lo he modificado, son mis validaciones, y claro, he puesto el código simple para que se entienda. Ahora, con el resto de su coment, cual sería el método correcto?? Me refiero a que yo ya valido mi password, el detalle es que se puede hacer con `password_verify` o comparando los hash como se hacía con SHA1 (por ejemplo)

Comment: Es que no entiendo cuál es el problema o la duda y los dos códigos que muestras son casi idénticos. ¿Podrías decirnos cuál es el código con que tienes duda exactamente y cuál es la duda? En cuanto a sha, el Manual advierte que no es recomendado,  por inseguro.

Comment: no no.. hay un error tecnico, y no lei todo ni los comentarios... yo nunca dije "verificar user y pass en la misma query"... dije que tiene que ser en el mismo momento, funcion, llamada... no en dos llamadas distintas....

Comment: por lo que logro comprender  tu duda viene de que si debes hacer un where con and? es decir validar tanto usuario como password a nivel de base de datos?
la respuesta simple seria solo usuario, ya que el usuario debe ser unico para cada acceso y de ese resultado validas el password, dado que el password a nivel de base de datos no coincidira al menos que vuelvas a encriptarlo y luego hagas la query.

Comment: tu pregunta esta basada en opiniones... no hay un **Es Correcto** o **Eso es Incorrecto**

Comment: en cuanto a lo que te comento @gbianchi es que limites la mas posible los request para tus necesidades ... el request de loggin debe hacer todo lo necesario a la responsabilidad de loggin en el backend ... no deben haver 2 request ... **esto si es incorrecto**...

Comment: en teoria te hace falta controlar si el usuario existe que vas a mostrar en el frontend ...  es algo que puedes hacer antes de verificar la pass ... en el mismo script...

Comment: Lo que si veo y te puedo sugerir es que comiences a trabajar con entidades en lugar de fabricar queries y codigo en linea que al final puede ser un problema, si vas a dar mantenimiento, en mi Framework personal la clase User (entidad) tiene la capacidad de darme cualquier cosa relacionada a: Datos, Login, Permisos

Comment: algo como $User->Loggin("usuario","password") deben poder retornar un true, false  y el error detectado si existe ...

Comment: En mi opinión, creo que se trata de la eficiencia no tanto como de la seguridad. En ambos casos (verificar los dos a la vez o por separado) compruebas que exista el usuario y que la clave sea correcta. Al menos teóricamente una de las dos opciones es más eficiente, lo cual no es realmente relevante para una aplicación.

Comment: ok gbianchi, ahora entiendo su punto, espero que el error técnico sea que no entendí su frase. @Bryro así lo tengo ahora, creo que está bien entonces. Arkanis ya controlo lo del user en el front. En cuanto a las entidades, es hacer clases y funciones o manejar las querys como las maneja Laravel?? que convierte las tablas a objetos y luego solo se accede a ellos? Tiene algún recurso para poder hacerlo en código puro?? Yo domino Laravel pero por lo general prefiero hacer las cosas pequeñas o personales en código puro. Juancarlos cual es la mas eficiente? passqord_verify o comparar los hash??

Comment: @Yenn, las entidades son clases (PHP) que están diseñadas para guardar/recuperar/ modificar datos. Son la Base de los ORM's como Eloquent de Laravel o Doctrine de Symfony.

Comment: como indica OCHOA, en el camino escucharas el termino ORM, en palabras singulares no es mas que algunas clases preparadas para obtener informacion y administrarlas de las base de datos en formato de Objetos, netamente aplicando POO (Programacion Orientada a Objetos) y hay distintas capas de responsabilidad:

Comment: por ejemplo una clase usuario debe poder heredar o expandicer e incluir a la clase Permisos y la Clase Datos .... asi como debe tambien estas clases tener acceso a la clase Base de datos, que en teoria esta debe recibir Estructuras preparadas para hacer consultas y administrar en general la base de datos ... estoy preparandote algo un poco mas complejo de lo que has realizado...

Comment: En terminos de eficiencia, depende de que punto de vista sea la "eficiencia": **para la ejecucion:** seria implementar esto en un solo request... **eficiencia en el desarrollo y mantenimiento** seria segregar las cosas por su responsabilidad ... imagina que tengas que validar si alguien tiene permiso desde multiples panatallas en el momento que se carga....

Comment: es preferible un $User->validatePermison($idForm); en lugar de escribir y mantener Querryes y conexiones en cada una de tus archivos php

Answer (score 1):

Te doy un ejemplo de cómo lo haría yo...

> IMHO no existe un camino realmente correcto, hay diferentes formas de hacer lo mismo y es muy amplia la documentación existente.

Lectura recomendada como punto básico de inicio: https://phptherightway.com/#password_hashing (la versión en inglés por que no he tenido tiempo de subir la traducción a español).

Primero que nada separaremos las responsabilidades en una Entidad: *Usuario* y una clase de la capa de abstracción *Core* de un pseudoframework, para que maneje y administre la base de datos:

> //AS-IS solo como ejemplo, puede no funcionar, no fue testeado

**Ejemplo de la clase Base de Datos:**

```
<?php


class BaseDeDatos
{
    private $pdo;
    private $query;
    private $param;

    public function __construct($host, $dbName, $usuario, $contrasena)
    {
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName", $usuario, $contrasena);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("Error de conexión: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    
//Implementamos Getter and Setter

    public function setQuery($query)
    {
        $this->query = $query;
    }
    
    public function getQuery()
    {
        return $this->query;
    }
        
    public function setParam($param)
    {
        $this->param = $param;
    }
        
    public function getParam($param)
    {
        return $this->param;
    }
    public function getData()
    {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($this->getQuery());
            
            foreach($this->getParam() as $bind => $clouse)
            {
                $stmt->bindParam(":".$bind, $clouse);
            }
            
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("Error al validar el inicio de sesión: " . $e->getMessage());
        }


    }

    // Aqui puede meter cualquier otro metodo que te ayude a la gestion de la base de datos... y ya saber que siempre que bayas a interactuar con la base de datos, simplemente llamas a esta clase e implementar los Querys y datos
}
```

**Ejemplo de la clase Usuario:**

```
class Usuario
{
//Aqui NO implementamos Getter and Setter me dio pereza, y creo que ya debes poder hacerlo

    private $nombreUsuario;
    private $contrasena;
    private $baseDeDatos;

    public function __construct($usuario) //colocal contraseña como null puede ayudar a que no sea necesario pasar la contraseña si lo que se implementa no lo requiere
    {
        $this->baseDeDatos = new BaseDeDatos("nombre_del_servidor", "nombre_de_la_base_de_datos", "nombre_de_usuario", "contraseña"); //preferiria establecer constantes para el acceso a la base de datos y evitar pasar parametros de esta forma
        $this->nombreUsuario = $nombreUsuario;
    }

    public function validarLogin($password)
    {
        $this->baseDeDatos->setQuery("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre_usuario = :nombreUsuario");
        $this->baseDeDatos->setParams(['nombreUsuario'=>$this->$user]);
        $result = $this->baseDeDatos->getData();
        
        if ($result && password_verify($password, $result['contrasena'])) {
            return [true, 'Hello '.$this->$user.' Success Loggin!!!'];
        }else{
            return [false, 'Invalid Username: '.$this->$user.' or Password: '.$password];
        }
    }

    // Aqui puede meter cualquier otro metodo que te ayude a la gestion de usuario ...
}
```

**Implementación:**

```
// Ejemplo de uso:

$usuario = new Usuario($user);

list($status, $smg) = $usuario->validarLogin($password);

if ($status) {
    echo $smg;
} else {
    echo $smg;
}
```

En general esto puede ser más eficiente tanto para el request (la parte técnica) como para el mantenimiento (desarrollo) aunque no estoy implementando el tipado fuerte que es tendencia hoy en día con php 7.4 en adelante, ni estoy implementando férreamente un patrón de diseño: (singleton, etc.)

El siguiente paso puede ser implementar un sistema de *control de error y log* más un subsistema de *query Builder*.

Otra cosa: el hecho de que manejes y comprendas las funcionalidad de frameworks como Laravel y Symfony no te hace conocedor del porqué de las cosas en php; hay un mundo detrás de los framework que los desarrolladores en general suelen desconocer, ya que en el desarrollo impera la productividad y no necesariamente conocer a detalle cómo funcionan las cosas, esto solo lo aplican las personas que o son perfeccionistas o tienen un alto conocimiento de la programación nativa en php (+ de 10 años).

Comment: Gracias, tendré muy en cuenta esto.