# Código inicio sesión php no funciona

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

La consulta SQL es correcta y los inputs de texto están bien enlazados. Tengo un sistema de register que funciona, por eso creo que no es problema de el MySQL. Poniendo las contraseñas correctas siempre aparece que los datos introducidos no son válidos. En mi opinión el error se debe a que la contraseña introducida no se "encripta" bien y por eso lo de como mala. Aquí hos dejo el código a ver si alguien puede encontrar algún error y ayudarme por favor.

````
if (isset($_SESSION['encryption_key'])) {
     $encryption_key = $_SESSION['encryption_key'];
} else {
    $encryption_key = random_bytes(32);
    $_SESSION['encryption_key'] = $encryption_key;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

$errores = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (!isset($_POST['user'])) {
        $errores .= '<div class="alert alert-danger d-flex align-items-center" role="alert"><svg class="bi flex-shrink-0 me-2" role="img" aria-label="Danger:"><use xlink:href="#exclamation-triangle-fill"/></svg><div>Please enter a username</div></div>';
    } else {
        $user = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['user']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }

    $password = $_POST['password'];

    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login', 'root', '');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $statement = $conexion->prepare('
        SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = :user'
    );
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':user' => $user
    ));

    $result = $statement->fetch();
    if ($result !== false) {
        $salt = hex2bin($result['salt']);
        $stored_key = hex2bin($result['pass']);
        $pepper = 'jkdg2wi3478e3dc902jd2398yf2';
        $passpepper = $password . $pepper;

        $keyLength = 20;
        $iterations = 600000;
        $generated_key = openssl_pbkdf2($passpepper, $salt, $keyLength, $iterations, 'sha512');

        if ($generated_key == $stored_key) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            $errores .= '<div class="alert alert-danger d-flex align-items-center" role="alert"><svg class="bi flex-shrink-0 me-2" role="img" aria-label="Danger:"><use xlink:href="#exclamation-triangle-fill"/></svg><div>The data you entered are incorrects</div></div>';
        }
    }
}

require 'views/login.view.php' ?>```
````

Comment: de donde sacaste que asi se manejan las contraseñas???

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover Como se hace entonces? ¿Qué otra manera hay?

Comment: [Lee este tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/605265/implementaci%c3%b3n-de-password-verify-y-password-hash-para-la-validaci%c3%b3n-de-usua) pueda que te ayude en algo.

Comment: @OCHOA gracias...   

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Implementación de password\_verify() y password\_hash() para la validación de usuarios en el login](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/605265/implementaci%c3%b3n-de-password-verify-y-password-hash-para-la-validaci%c3%b3n-de-usua)