# PHP password_verify error al verificar

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

soy novato en esto de PHP, y la verdad que no encuentro el error en este código login la verdad, la base de datos está bien puesto. El código pepper también está bien puesto. Lo que pasa es que al ingresar datos correctos la página se me redirige a la página register.php. El problema es que no se que está pasando mal en lo que se refiere en la verificación de la contraseña ingresada en el input de texto. Por favor necesito ayuda, a ver si podéis encontrar algún error en el código.

`````
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $user = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['user']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $errores = '';

    if (empty($user) || empty($password)) {
        $errores .= '<li>Please fill all the gaps.</li>';
    } else {
        try {
            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login', 'root', '');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = :user LIMIT 1');
        $statement->execute(array(':user' => $user));
        $result = $statement->fetch();

        if ($result == false) {
            $errores .= '<li>The user does not exist.</li>';
        } else {
            $salt = hex2bin($result['salt']);
            $hash = $result['pass'];
            $pepper = 'jkdg2wi3478e3dc902jd2398yf2';
            $passpepper = $password . $pepper;

            if (!password_verify($passpepper, $hash)) {
                $errores .= '<li>The password is incorrect.</li>';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($errores == '') {
        $encryption_key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);

        $encrypted_cookie_value = openssl_encrypt($user, 'AES-256-CBC', $encryption_key, 0, '0000000000000000');

        setcookie('user', $encrypted_cookie_value, time() + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60, '/', '', false, true);

        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}

require 'views/login.view.php';````


// Código INDEX.PHP otra página
<?php session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location: dashboard.php');
} else {
    header('Location: register.php');
}
?>
`````

Comment: Suponiendo que no está fallando el login, no se si será que estás olvidando inicializar las variables de sesión `$_SESSION['user']` y/u otras que hagan falta.

Comment: Que de diferente tiene a [esta pregunta tuya](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/617245/c%c3%b3digo-inicio-sesi%c3%b3n-php-no-funciona)??